# OPCUA removing Montior item c#

Tags: c#, opc, opc-ua

I am trying to remove monitor item from OPCUA server.First I remove items and apply changes then remove subscription from session.In server I am still able to see some monitor items in inactive state.What is correct way to remove items from subscription before closing the client

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to close the client down you don't need to delete each monitored item, you can just delete each subscription.

And even then you don't even need to do that yourself - just call the CloseSession service with the `deleteSubscriptions` parameter set to `true`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ,technically I am still doing delete subscription but opcua server is still maintaining some monitor item as in inactive state

Comment: This sounds like a problem with the server to me. How are you viewing / determining there are still monitored items in the server?

Comment: There is a tool with Matrikon server which provide information about monitor items which are subscribed.When I am subscribed to 100 items it will show 100 items subscribed.Once I end session it will show few items e.g 20 items as inactive